# bind_rows in a list even though the class() is different

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, data-manipulation, tidy

I have a list below what I don't wanna do is to change the `class(Category)` in `df2`. The code should change the class(category) and assign it category in the `list()` object. How to get around this? Many thanks in advance.

```
df1 <- data_frame(ID = paste0(LETTERS[1],1:4), valueA = seq(0.1,0.4,0.1), Category= "Apples" )
df2 <- data_frame(ID = paste0(LETTERS[1],5:8), valueB = seq(0.1,0.4,0.1),  Category= seq(0.1,0.4,0.1))
df3 <- data_frame(ID = paste0(LETTERS[1],9:12), valueC = seq(0.1,0.4,0.1),  Category= "Apples3")

list1 <- list(df1, df2, df3);list1
bind_rows(list1)

Error in `bind_rows()`:
! Can't combine `..1$Category` <character> and `..2$Category` <double>.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: In R, dataframe cannot have more than one class of values in the same column. Therefore you cannot have numeric (e.g. `df2$Category`) together with character (e.g. `df1$Category`, `df3$Category`) in the same column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could convert all the columns to `character` and then automatically change the type with `type.convert`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
 map_dfr(list1, ~ .x %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character))) %>% 
  type.convert(as.is= TRUE)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 12 × 5
   ID    valueA Category valueB valueC
   <chr>  <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 A1       0.1 Apples     NA     NA  
 2 A2       0.2 Apples     NA     NA  
 3 A3       0.3 Apples     NA     NA  
 4 A4       0.4 Apples     NA     NA  
 5 A5      NA   0.1         0.1   NA  
 6 A6      NA   0.2         0.2   NA  
 7 A7      NA   0.3         0.3   NA  
 8 A8      NA   0.4         0.4   NA  
 9 A9      NA   Apples3    NA      0.1
10 A10     NA   Apples3    NA      0.2
11 A11     NA   Apples3    NA      0.3
12 A12     NA   Apples3    NA      0.4
```

---

Or we could `nest` it

```
map_dfr(list1, ~ .x %>% nest(data = Category))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 12 × 5
   ID    valueA data             valueB valueC
   <chr>  <dbl> <list>            <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 A1       0.1 <tibble [1 × 1]>   NA     NA  
 2 A2       0.2 <tibble [1 × 1]>   NA     NA  
 3 A3       0.3 <tibble [1 × 1]>   NA     NA  
 4 A4       0.4 <tibble [1 × 1]>   NA     NA  
 5 A5      NA   <tibble [1 × 1]>    0.1   NA  
 6 A6      NA   <tibble [1 × 1]>    0.2   NA  
 7 A7      NA   <tibble [1 × 1]>    0.3   NA  
 8 A8      NA   <tibble [1 × 1]>    0.4   NA  
 9 A9      NA   <tibble [1 × 1]>   NA      0.1
10 A10     NA   <tibble [1 × 1]>   NA      0.2
11 A11     NA   <tibble [1 × 1]>   NA      0.3
12 A12     NA   <tibble [1 × 1]>   NA      0.4
```

Answer (score 1):

We can convert *Category* column to a *list*, then row-bind, this way we can keep the class:

```
#convert Category column into list class
list1 <- lapply(list(df1, df2, df3),
                function(i){ mutate(i, Category = as.list(Category)) })
#then bind
out <- bind_rows(list1)

#check class
class(unlist(out[1, "Category"]))
# [1] "character"
class(unlist(out[5, "Category"]))
# [1] "numeric"
```